# Как изменить expired password администратора windows через сессию обычного пользователя?

Tags: windows

Есть удаленный компьютер, на котором есть две учетный записи: adm (администратор) и usr (обычный пользователь).

К usr есть удаленный доступ через Teamviewer, командная строка и т.д.

У adm случился expired password - это когда ты не можешь войти в учетную запись, пока не задашь новый пароль. Т.е. это принудительная смена пароля. Проблемы сменить expired password, когда компьютер у тебя под боком, нет. При входе вводишь сарый пароль, новый и его подтверждение.

**Старый пароль adm известен.**

Можно ли через usr обновить пароль adm? Вызвать через командную строку или еще как-то запрос на изменение пароля adm, где, естественно, потребуется ввод прежнего пароля adm (который мы знаем).

*Запускать приложения от имени adm не получается, так как нужна смена пароля, а как вызвать этот запрос из другой учетной записи (и возможно ли это) непонятно.*

Comment: а в учетных записях пользователя пробовали поменять пароль?

Comment: Тут получается как замкнутный круг, сменить пароль админу я не могу, пока не повышу права до админа, а повысить права до админа я не могу, так как ожидается смена пароля. Нужно получить доступ к той форме (старый пароль, новый, подтверждение), которую мы видим на экране входа adm, но доступ к этой форме нужно получить не с экрана входа adm, а из учетки usd.

Comment: А если log off сделать и попытаться log in с предварительным выбором пользователя?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что имеется в виду, нужны подробности. Выйти из учетной записи? Если выйти из учетной записи, то удаленное соединение пропадает, мы ведь не можем сервис без прав администратора запустить, т.е. мы перестаем видеть экран при выходе из учетки usr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983996/updating-expired-administrator-password-remotely-without-windows-rdp/44987566#44987566

---

Через [NetUserChangePassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370650(v=vs.85).aspx) можно изменить пароль без повышения привелегий.

---

Для Java разработчиков:
https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

```
Netapi32.INSTANCE.NetUserChangePassword(Kernel32Util.getComputerName(), "user-login", "old-password", "new-password");
```